# Why is the window re-scaling/shrinking in output when no resize and size constraints are in place?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm just new and messing around with the WPF C#.

I noticed that the design view and have some minor differences. Most noticeable at the button.

Design View:

[image]

Ouput # 1:

[image]

Ouput # 2:

[image]

It seems that the window/container is resizing/shrinking even when both min and max width's and height's were set with fixed values and resize mode is set to NoResize.

I could easily deal with some of the controls by setting up the vertical and horizontal alignments since the adjustments are not too noticeable, but for the Add button the differences are noticeable from the supposed output.

I did try setting the min size of the button so that it would not be affected by the resizing and there would still be space for the margins but the button properly renders only a part of it. (please see output 1)

The only compromise that I could is to set both vertical and horizontal alignment to stretch and not put any size constraints on the button but the button would end up shrinking from its original size. (please see output 2)

Here's the XAML for the window.

```
<Window x:Class="Game_Viewer.NewApp"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Game_Viewer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Add New Program" Height="155" Width="250" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="#FF515151" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" MinHeight="155" MinWidth="250">
    <Grid Margin="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image x:Name="appicon_img" Margin="10,10,0,0" Source="Resources/menu_bg.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="apppath_txtbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,55,0,0" Width="154" Foreground="White" Background="#FF6E6E6E" Text="Program Path" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF707070" MaxLines="1" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button Content="Search" Margin="169,55,10,0" Click="BrowseApp_Click" Foreground="White" Background="#FF515151" FontWeight="Medium" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="add_btn" Content="Add Program" Margin="72,89,72,8" Foreground="White" Background="#FF515151" Click="AddProgram_Click" FontWeight="Medium" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" MinHeight="30" MinWidth="100"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="appname_txtbox" Margin="50,10,10,0" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Foreground="White" Text="Program Name" MaxLines="1" IsUndoEnabled="True" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="#FF707070" FontWeight="Medium" Background="#FF6E6E6E" Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I would like to know a solution or round-about for this kind of issue.

It's not really a problem having this issue as it is only aesthetic but I would at least know the reason why this is happening. And could you refer me to good tutorials for wpf using c#.

Thanks in advance and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Don't position controls by margins with respect to the window borders. That's not how you do it in WPF. Do use layout containers.

Comment: @gdir has a good suggestion. I'll go one step further. DON"T USE THE DESIGNER :)

Comment: Personally I find the Visual Studio designer inaccurate as you did, if I have to use the designer I like to load up my app into Blend, I find the designer there much better, best regards.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'll do avoid using the margins and will add more layout containers in the future. I'll try not using the designer all too much until I'm used to it, thanks. I'll also try the Blend app see where things will go. Thanks guys!